# Querying DUAL table and UNION ALL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like below,

```
 SELECT 1 AS SI, 'JAN' AS MoN FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, 'FEB' FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3, 'MAR' FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 4, 'APR' FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 5, 'MAY' FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 6, 'JUN' FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 7, 'JUL' FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 8, 'AUG' FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 9, 'SEP' FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 10, 'OCT' FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 11, 'NOV' FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 12, 'DEC' FROM DUAL ;
```

Would you please assist any best alternative or any performance improvement here ?

Comment: It's as simple as it could it get. I'd say store it in a table.

Comment: Oracle lacks standard SQL's `VALUE` constructor, so the clumsy `select ... from dual union all ...` is what we must use instead. You can vote here for featuring the `VALUE` constructor in a future release: https://community.oracle.com/ideas/13697

Answer (score 4):

try it

```
SELECT
  LEVEL AS ID,
  TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(DATE '1000-01-01', LEVEL-1), 'MON') 
FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12;
```

Comment: Well done. If you want English abbreviations, you should say so by adding `'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'` as a third parameter for `TO_CHAR`. You mistakenly added `LEVEL` instead of `LEVEL-1`. And I replaced the string leteral that you converted to date by a date literal for readability.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT to_char(to_date(((12 -level+1)),'MM'), 'MON') display, 12 -level+1 internal FROM DUAL
connect by level <=12
order by internal asc

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page. Also, please make use of the formatting possibilities we provide in order to make your code more readable.